# Can a single location on earth witness solar eclipse totality 2 times during a single eclipse event?

Tags: solar-eclipse

The question came to my mind when I saw a visualisation of the path of the moon (relative to the sun - the sun is kept centered in the graphic, and only the moon moves) as its seen from a particular location during a solar eclipse.

This reddit post has the visualisation - https://www.reddit.com/r/delhi/comments/h0u878/in_10_days_there_will_be_a_partial_solar_eclipse/

In the visualisation, the moon appears to move towards the sun, and then retraces its path (almost).

If the moon crosses the sun, and then makes its way back, it is possible for the moon to cause 2 totality events at the same location on the earth.

Is this actually possible? Why or why not?

Has it even happened in the past? When and in which location?

When and where will it happen again?

Comment: Reminds me of the wonderful short film "Frame of Reference"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJMYoj4hHqU

Answer (score 3):

No.

The video has been made so that the sun remains at the centre, but so that "up" is still "up relative to the horizon". This means that the shape of the crescent of the moon is how it will appear in the sky.  The turning of the Earth makes the direction of the moon relative to the sun appear to change.

Comment: Do you mean that the video switches directions midway (maybe around 12 noon)?